# State transition change state name by boolean

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 1.5. I have this piece of code in my app to do some processing when change between states:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {               
                vm.isGrey = toParams.isGrey;

                NavService.setPreviousState({
                    state: fromState,
                    params: fromParams
                });

                if (fromState.name !== toState.name) {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            });
```

It turns that after triggering a `$state.go('stateName')` in some point on the app
the `fromState` param came with all the correct values except that `fromState.name` came with a boolean object **true/false** instead state name.

I'm pulling my hair out because I can't find in my code when this state name is replaced with this boolean value.

Comment: is `fromState.name` valid at given point(inside $stateChangeSuccess handler)?

Comment: yes, it is. this code execute every time the app goes from state to another, issue appear in nested views with two or more states stacked.

Comment: sorry, looking from now my question seems useless. Do you have any existing fiddler to debug around this issue?

Comment: I'm not longer working in the project that generated the question, thanks for trying to help, have a good day.